# GZip response on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, gzip, iis-express

I want to compress responses coming from my IIS Express driven web application. We're using IIS Express as local development webserver and IIS on staging and on our build machines. I have found many guides on enabling gzipped responses on IIS but none for IIS Express. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can enable compression in IIS Express, just like for IIS.

1. Start command prompt and go to IIS Express installation folder (`%PROGRAMFILES%\IIS Express`)
2. Run following command

> appcmd set config -section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:true

To add compression for JSON run the following two commands from the IIS Express installation directory:

> appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.json',mimeType='application/json']
>
> appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost

Make sure to restart IIS Express.

Comment: I get gzip-compression on javascript files and html files. But the json still doesn't get compressed. I've added the mimetype "application/json" to both the web config and app config. Any ideas?

Comment: Run following two commands from the IIS Express installation directory and see if that works (make sure that you restart IIS Express after running these commands). (1) appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.json',mimeType='application/json']                 (2) appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost

Comment: You can omit the first command--the one that modifies staticContent--if you don't serve .json files statically. If you're like me, you only serve JSON in HTTP POST responses.

Comment: The same commands work for IIS 8 as well, and I assume for 7/7.5.

Comment: You can also edit the .config file directly in ``{MyDocumentsFolder}\IISExpress\applicationhost.config``

Comment: to go to IIS Express folder using CMD, you can also try : `pushd C:\Program Files\IIS Express`

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2019 I found the above does not work, as the `applicationhost.config` file is unique to the project. This file is stored in `.vs\<solution_name>\config\applicationhost.config`. For VS 2017 it isnt in the solution subfolder.

Thus the solution for me was to replace `<httpCompression/>` with the following.

```
<httpCompression directory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%IIS_BIN%\gzip.dll" />
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
```