# Compression Filter on MVC Page is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-compression, yslow, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have a MVC5 Web Application. I used Compression Filter on my controller from [This Site](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/my-top-5-aspnet-mvc-actionfilters-AD)

Everything works but looks like still my page is not compressed. 
I use YSlow Chrome extension to check my page but it reports that GZip compression is not applied on my page. I'm testing my web app in VS 2015 (debug mode) using IIS Express.

Am I doing something wrong? or YSlow extension is wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529076/gzip-compression-not-working-asp-net-mvc5

Comment: Or maybe this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102743/gzip-response-on-iis-express

Comment: The second solution is not preferred as I will finally want to deploy my app on web hosting that I don't have control on IIS. For the first link, I had tried that and it looks a very good solution but my app was unstable on web hosting. I'll try it again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```