# Implement GZIP OwinMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin-middleware

I'm trying to implement API Gzip Compration OwinMiddleware component.

```
 public class ApiResponseCompression : OwinMiddleware
    {
        private const string AcceptEncodingHeader = "Accept-Encoding";
        private const string ContentEncodingHeader = "Content-Encoding";
        private const string ContentTypeHeader = "Content-Type";
        private const string GzipEncoding = "gzip";
        private const string JsonContentType = "application/json";

        private readonly OwinMiddleware _next;

        public ApiResponseCompression(OwinMiddleware next)
            : base(next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;

            if (request.Headers.ContainsKey(AcceptEncodingHeader) &&
                request.Headers[AcceptEncodingHeader].Contains(GzipEncoding))
            {

 /* I need somehow to obtain response content from context then compress it (gzip) and put back*/

                context.Response.Headers.Remove(ContentTypeHeader);
                context.Response.Headers.Add(ContentEncodingHeader, new[] { GzipEncoding });
                context.Response.Headers.Add(ContentTypeHeader, new[] { JsonContentType });
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

I feel that the answer's in there somewhere, but a really had little exprience with OwinMiddleware. I usually used to work with normal asp.net httpContext, and it has content property, but IOwinContext doesn't.

Q: How can i resolve my issue? what best practise with OwinMiddleware i should use?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102743/gzip-response-on-iis-express or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip

Comment: But what if we select self host?

Comment: You could try the [Owin.Compression package](http://thorium.github.io/Owin.Compression/).

Comment: Also ask yourself, why you would care about gzipping in a self-host project? If it's for performance reasons, you probably shouldn't self-host it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that under advisement